# Регулярные выражения Notepad++

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Есть несколько текстовых файлов с форматированными статьями, но так исторически сложилось, что текст слился в одну строку, и заголовки идут слитно с предыдущим текстом. Нужно перед каждой большой буквой (в верхнем регистре) поставить перенос строки.
Т.е. сейчас текст имеет такой вид "ParagraphTitleParagraph", нужно сделать чтобы было так:

"Paragraph

Title

Paragraph"

Можно ли это осуществить?

Comment: а вы уверены что внутри параграфов и заголовков не будет больших букв?

Comment: Добавлю, перенос строки нужно добавить только в случае, если перед большой буквой не находится символ пробела, а только другие буквы (т.е. если текст слился).

Comment: Grundy, вы правы, добавила пост выше.

Comment: буквы русские или английские или и такие и такие?

Comment: еще большая буква внутри предложения и в  начале может быть в кавычках. еще скобки

Comment: Grundy, буквы и русские и английские.

Comment: splash58, действительно, это тоже нужно учитывать...

Answer (score 1):

Нажмите `ctrl - H` , поставьте режим поиска - регулярное выражение и впишите
Найти: `([^\ ])([A-ZА-ЯЁ])`
Заменить на: `$1\r\n$2`

Comment: Рекомендую изменить на `(\S)([A-ZА-ЯЁ])` потому что перенос строки, табуляция, неразрывный пробел за которым будет следовать заглавная буква- тоже удовлетворят Вашему выражению.

Answer (score 0):

Для английского текста можно использовать следующее регулярное выражение

```
([a-z])([A-Z])
```

В поле замены указать

```
$1\n$2
```

А также выставить галочку "Match Case"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если предыдущее предложение заканчивается знаком препинания или цифрой?

Comment: Grundy в np++ никаких проблем с русским тестами в регулярках нет. Может, только с Ё

Comment: @Darth, тогда не найдет :)

Comment: @splash58, если текст англоязычный их даже и проверять не стоит

Comment: Grundy как-то я не подумал, что это текст потенциального противника 6)